# ogr2ogr export to KML from SQLite, when using SELECT for fields Linestrings are lost

Tags: kml, sql, ogr2ogr

I'm using:

```
ogr2ogr -sql "SELECT * FROM 'trails_utm_utf8' ORDER BY name ASC" -f KML trails.kml trails_utm_utf8.sqlite -s_srs EPSG:900913 -t_srs EPSG:4326
```

to reorder, re-project and export to KML from a vectorlayer with linestrings kept in a SQlite.db. Now, I'd like to ommit the creation of the ExtendedData by the KML driver and tried so by putting the columns 'name' and 'description' from my SQLite file to SELECT - but strangely this will end up in a KML without any linestrings from the input file.

```
ogr2ogr -sql "SELECT name, description FROM 'trails_utm_utf8' ORDER BY name ASC" -f KML trails.kml trails_utm_utf8.sqlite -s_srs EPSG:900913 -t_srs EPSG:4326
```

Any ideas how to export only the fields/columns 'name' and 'description' and avoid that all other fields from the input file are put to the ExtendeData?

Comment: I would try "SELECT geometry, name, description..."

Comment: Of course, thanks mate! Actually this was my first guess, but I tried "SELECT geom,.." which is obviously false!

Comment: @user30184, put it as an answer and I'll check it!